# Delete all keys from the Keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I need to delete all the keys stored at the keychain. Problem is that they are not static strings (I create them using "the user name + static string") and I have to implement something like a reset app option.

At the moment of the app implementation (couple of years ago) I used a library called FXKeychain to access the keychain but didn't seem to have an option like that.

Is there any other way to do it?

I'm working with Objective-C.

I found this code searching about it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *query = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue, (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes,
                              (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitAll, (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit,
                              nil];
NSArray *secItemClasses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassInternetPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                           (__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity,
                           nil];

for (id secItemClass in secItemClasses) {
    [query setObject:secItemClass forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];

    CFTypeRef result = NULL;
    SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &result);
    NSLog(@"%@", (__bridge id)result);
    if (result != NULL) CFRelease(result);
}
```

But I don't totally understand it and I think it's not working (maybe it has to be with the library I used?)

Answer (score 0):

To delete the keychain items added from your app, this should work fine :
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] accessGroup:nil];

[keychain resetKeychainItem];

did you already try?